# How to find intersection points between a line and polyfit in opencv?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am currently working on lane detection on opencv. I detected right and left line  pixel coordinates for lane in seperate parameters such as:

- left_line_x (= contains pixel x coordinates that belongs left line)
- left_line_y
- right_line_x
- right_line_y

And then created 2 polyfits with them which are;

```
left_line = np.polyfit(left_line_y, left_line_x, 2)
```

and same for right.

Because there are many pixel points that I've detected (59168 for only left for example) I want to draw imaginary horizontal lines to the image and then look for intersection points between those lines and line polyfits (left_line).

How can I do this? Especially need help on the intersection part. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want. You want all pixel coordinates of the lane edges?

Comment: I want to draw a horizontal line on the image, let's say one horizontal line in the middle of the image. How do I get the intersection points between this horizontal line and left_line polyfit?

Answer (score 1):

2 degrees of freedom does not match the inputs given in the original problem. I've assumed 1 degree of freedom for the solution below.

To find the intersection of lines given the output from numpy.polyfit(), try the following:

```
x0 = -(left_line[1] - right_line[1])/(left_line[0]-right_line[0])
y0 = x0*left_line[0] + left_line[1]
```

Comment: I want to find the intersection points between a "new" drawed horizontal line, and left_line polyfit. Not the intersection point between left and right line polyfits. Or did I misunderstand what you've wrote?

Comment: In that case, set right_line[1] to the y-intercept of the new, drawn horizontal line and sent right_line[0] to 0. This should give you the intercept.